# Make dynamic array with values returned from foreach

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have values returned that way after a calculation to take the percentage.

```
     $school = $api->schools;
    
            foreach ($school as $key => $value){
    $name = $value->id;

    $data = DB::table('sys_users')
        ->where('schoolid','=',$name)
        ->get();

    $exist1 = count($data)*4;

    $datarecord = DB::table('sys_record')
        ->join('sys_users', 'sys_users.id_jovens', '=', 'sys_record.id_user')
        ->where('sys_users.schoolid','=',$name)
        ->get();

    $correct1 = count($datarecord);

            function porcentagem_nx($parcial,$total) {
                return ($parcial * 100) / $total;
            }

    $worldone[$value->id] = porcentagem_nx($correct1, $exist1);
    
    // Because you already used $data above, I chose a different name
    // for this array.
    $items[] = [
        "id"       => $value->id,
        "name"     => $value->name,
        "worldone" => $worldone,
    ];
}
    
            dd($items);
```

I will use it on the datatable so it is necessary for my manual tests to be like the one below, but dynamic.

```
$data = [
                [
                "id" => 1,
                "name" => "Brand",
                "worldone" => $worldone,
                ],
                [
                    "id" => 2,
                    "name" => "Just",
                    "worldone" => $worldone,
                ],
            ];
```

I'm having trouble bringing the information from the worldone variable out of the foreach and making the array dynamic for all array records in the variable $school.

Comment: Where are you getting the values for the ID and name elements of the `$data` array that you're trying to achieve? Are they coming from the `$value` object in the `foreach` loop?

Comment: @dhnwebpro $api->schools; is array with key and value.

Comment: It looks like `porcentagem_nx()` is being declared twice somewhere. Is it declared in a Controller in the same namespace? `App\Http\Controllers\RelatoriosController.php` and somewhere else? If you need a second declaration, perhaps you could rename it to something like `porcentageem_nx2()` and see if it clears up the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong in this answer, but I'm going to take a stab at it. Let me know if I'm off base because I'm making some assumptions that may not be correct. The resulting value you want to get out of the `foreach` loop looks like this:

```
$data = [
    [
        "id"       => 1,
        "name"     => "name",
        "worldone" => $worldone,
    ],
];
```

So my suggestion is something like this for your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($school as $key => $value){
    $name = $value->id;

    $data = DB::table('sys_users')
        ->where('schoolid','=',$name)
        ->get();

    $exist1 = count($data)*4;

    $datarecord = DB::table('sys_record')
        ->join('sys_users', 'sys_users.id_jovens', '=', 'sys_record.id_user')
        ->where('sys_users.schoolid','=',$name)
        ->get();

    $correct1 = count($datarecord);

    $worldone[$value->id] = porcentagem_nx($correct1, $exist1);
    
    // Because you already used $data above, I chose a different name
    // for this array.
    $items[] = [
        "id"       => $value->id,
        "name"     => $value->name,
        "worldone" => $worldone,
    ];
}
```

The `$items` variable will have all of the items set up according to what you specified. I'm assuming that the value of `id` and `name` are in the `$value` object in your `foreach` loop. If this is wrong let me know and I can update the answer to show where they should be coming from.

You can loop through `$items` or call something like `print_r($items[0]);` and the output should give you something similar to the `$data` array above.